# Python module xhtml2pdf - pages count outside footer

Tags: python, pdf, xhtml2pdf

I use the `xhtml2pdf` module to generate a PDF document and I want to use the `pdf:pagecount` tag in a normal text, i.e. outside the footer.

When I use the `footer_content` class for the `div` element with the `pdf:pagecount` tag, the page number and page count is properly generated.

```
<div id="footer_content">Page <pdf:pagenumber> of <pdf:pagecount>
</div>
```

However, when I do not use the `footer_content` class, the `pdf:pagenumber` tag prints 0 for all pages and the tag `pdf:pagecount` does not print anything at all.

[image]

```
<div>Page <pdf:pagenumber>
    of <pdf:pagecount>
</div>
```

[image]

Is there some solution how to use the `pdf:pagecount` tag outside the `footer_content` class?